# How to create a SPA site not refreshing header and menu

Tags: next.js

I am trying to create a SPA page, where I want to refresh only the center content. Is that possible to achieve using nextjs? I am not being able to resue Header and Left Menu. For an enterprise app that is very expensive to render for every page we need to load.

Can I keep Header and Menu without reload(rendering again) when I open a new page?

I have tried Dynamic Loading, but it also renders every time.